# What is the complexity o(1) or o(n)?

Tags: java

In the following loop is the complexity O(1) or is it O(n)?

```
for(int j = 0; j < Math.random() * 1000 + 1; j++)
```

I don't know the number of times it would run through the loop so shouldn't it be O(n)?

Comment: please format your code

Comment: Its o(1) because n is the number of input. There is no input. Your code will  run for a function of 1000, which is O(1)

Comment: Before thinking of complexity in terms of O(n), you need to first define what n is...

Comment: The real question is: why does it matter? This seems like a very silly function to analyze asymptotically. There are many (infinitely many!) O(1) operations that are *slower* than an O(N) operation would be, at least for any arbitrary N you choose. So don't just use Big O notation blindly: figure out *what problem you're actually trying to solve* and see how Big O helps you solve it -- or not.

Answer (score 8):

Its `O(1)` because n is the input. There is no input in the code

```
for(int j =0 ;j<(Math.random()*1000+1);j++)
```

Your code will run for number of iteration which is a function of 1000 , hence `O(1)`

Comment: Let's not forget to say **The loop runs at most 1001 times irrespective of the value returned by `Math.random()`**  which is what exactly O(1) means. No matter what the input is, The program takes a constant time to execute even in the worst case scenario.

Answer (score -1):

Since its a random number generator, then the complexity n*1000+1 therefore O(n). If it where a static value like 1000+1 then complexity would have been O(1). Where n is the range of the possible result the function Math.Random() can output

Comment: Math.random outputs a double that is between 0 and 1, so the loop will be executed at most 1000 times.

Comment: @assylias today i learned, youre right thanks.